# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 White texteditor despite theme, login failing, usercontext cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently was having a lot of trouble with Visual Studio 2017..

1. My texteditor wouldn't properly use the default colours in themes.
2. I'd recieve errors when i tried to log in
3. extensioons/update + all account/user context information was
   broken.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to make this post because there wasn't a simple solution given for the texteditor /theme being broken and I solved it later after doing some research on other related issues.

To fix the broken themes,

Close VS, go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ and delete/rename a folder whose name starts with 15.0_.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/44015/c-editor-suddenly-turned-light-while-the-rest-of-v.html

Broken Theme example
[image: Broken theme]